# create table in which each value can be present at most once

Tags: mysql, sql

Say we have a database of mutual best-friends pairs (one can only have one best friend).

```
1,2
4,3
5,2 <-- 5 can't be best friends with 2, because 2 already is in a best-friend relationship. [INVALID]
2,1 <-- 1 and 2 is already present in the table, we don't want this redundancy. [INVALID]
```

To be clear, whether a friend pair is valid depends on the order of insertion. If we got the insertion order:

```
2,1
4,3
1,2  <--- [INVALID] 1 and 2 is already recorded in the DB.
```

Briefly put, I want a table in which each value can at most once:
How can I create a table in which each value at most can appear once?
This is what I got so far:

```
CREATE TABLE friends 
(
   ID_1 int UNIQUE,
   ID_2 int UNIQUE,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID_1, ID_2)
)
```

Comment: why is 1,2 valid and 5,2 is not valid? How do you decide which best-friend relationship is valid if there are multiple (1,2 / 5,2)?

Comment: (1,2) is valid because there hasn't already been recorded a best-friend relationship in which 1 and 2 is part of. If, say, (2,1) were to be inserted before (1,2); (1,2) would be invalid. I.e. it all depends of the order of insertion.

Comment: You probably will have to write a trigger to handle this.  Check constraints cannot use subqueries (and they won't work at all on MySQL version earlier than 8+).

Comment: ... and you need to make sure that the pairs are stored such that the lower id goes to id1 and higher goes to id2 (e.g. 5,2 should be stored as 2,5); that will ensure that primary key works as expected.

Comment: @SalmanA *the lower id goes to id1 and higher goes to id2* This is excess - there are LEAST() and GREATEST() function which solves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent versions of MySQL support [function-based indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts):

> MySQL 8.0.13 and higher supports functional key parts that index expression values rather than column or column prefix values.

What you want is an unique index on the the least and greatest of the values:

```
create unique index unq_bestfriends_friend1_friend2
    on bestfriends(least(friend1, friend2), greatest(friend1, friend2));
```

Since MySQL 5.7, you can do something similar iwth computed columns:

```
alter table bestfriends add least_friend int
    generated always as (least(friend1, friend2));
```

alter table bestfriends add greatest_friend int
        generated always as (greatest(friend1, friend2));

```
create unique index unq_bestfriends_friend1_friend2
    on bestfriends(least_friend, greatest_friend);
```